# Sorting and extracting pandas dataframe based on custom hierarchy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have dataframe as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'brand': ['Yum_Yum', 'Yum_Yum', 'Indomie', 'Indomie', 'Indomie', 'Boom_Boom', 'Boom_Boom'],
    'style': ['cup', 'box', 'cup', 'pack', 'pack', 'pack', 'pack'],
    'rating': [4, 4, 3.5, 15, 5, 2.3, 0]
})
```

I define a hierarchy as `#hierarchy --> 1 = pack, 2 = cup, 3= box` where pack is the highest priority and box is the lowest. I only want to keep one instance of each unique value in the brand column. This instance should have the highest priority value based on my hierarchy. If there are ties, then it can be split randomly.

So the resulting dataframe would look something like this:

```
brand   style   rating
Yum_Yum cup 4.0
Indomie pack    5.0
Boom_Boom   box 2.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try mapping the style to priority, sort, and drop duplicates:

```
priority = {'cup':2, 'box':3, 'pack':1}
df['style_rank'] = df['style'].map(priority)
df.sort_values('style_rank').drop_duplicates('brand')
```

Output:

```
       brand style  rating  style_rank
3    Indomie  pack    15.0           1
5  Boom_Boom  pack     2.3           1
0    Yum_Yum   cup     4.0           2
```

Comment: oh that's perfect, i was expecting it to be something like that.

Comment: I'll accept the answer as soon as I'm able to. 9 minutes